# Safe usage of Runtime.getRuntime.exec(String[])

Tags: java, injection, code-review, code-execution

I was reviewing code of an application that uses the following piece of Java code and wanted to know if the the use of exec() was susceptible to command injection.

```
public class FindFileInDir {
  public static void main(String[] args){
   try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String[] cmdArr = { "bash", "checkfileindirectory.sh", "<directory_to_search>", "<file_to_find>" };
        Process p = rt.exec(cmdArr);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
  }
}
```

To provide some context, the shell script is just a wrapper for the find command that searches for a file in a directory. It takes two arguments **directory_to_search** and **file_to_find**. The **directory_to_search** argument to the script is fixed but the user contains the **file_to_find** argument. Is there are payload that can be used to chain multiple bash commands in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran your program, linked to a `checkfileindirectory.sh` that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1 > param1.txt
echo $2 > param2.txt
```

As a test, I changed `"<file_to_find>"` to `"<file_to_find>;touch MikeWasHere.txt"`

```
String[] cmdArr = { "bash", "checkfileindirectory.sh", "<directory_to_search>", "<file_to_find>;touch MikeWasHere.txt" };
```

And I get this output:

```
➜  /tmp javac FindFileInDir.java
➜  /tmp java FindFileInDir 
➜  /tmp cat param1.txt 
<directory_to_search>
➜  /tmp cat param2.txt 
<file_to_find>;touch MikeWasHere.txt
➜  /tmp ls MikeWasHere.txt
ls: cannot access 'MikeWasHere.txt': No such file or directory
```

So *it looks like* java's rt.exec() is injection-safe.

---

[OWASP's page on command injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Command_Injection) has a paragraph about java's exec (emphasis mine):

> C’s system function passes its arguments to the shell (/bin/sh) to be parsed, whereas Runtime.exec tries to split the string into an array of words, then executes the first word in the array with the rest of the words as parameters. **Runtime.exec does NOT try to invoke the shell at any point.** The key difference is that much of the functionality provided by the shell that could be used for mischief (chaining commands using “&”, “&&”, “|”, “||”, etc, redirecting input and output) would simply end up as a parameter being passed to the first command

**That seems consistent with our experiment that java's rt.exec() is injection-safe.**